# I'd like to check the column and specify row_number()

Tags: postgresql

```
 name          type    grade       site                   date         num
  Toy           c        A       test.com               20210315        1
  Toy           c        B       test.com               20210315        2
  Toy           a        B       test.com               20210315        1
  Tool          a        A       gonggu.com             20210315        1
  Tool          a        c       gonggu.com             20210315        2
  Electronics   b        A       electro.com            20210315        1
  Electronics   b        B       electro.com            20210315        2
```

The result should be like that, but I don't know how to write a query.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data? I couldn't understand why your expected result been created.

Comment: Even if the site column values are the same, the num should be different if the type is different.
In other words, the same types should be tied to the same site. The ratings are in ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `ROW_NUMBER` as follows:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, type, site ORDER BY grade) num
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: If the site is different, the number must be changed to 1. The current solution does not change the number if the name is the same.

Comment: @yahoo2344 Then add `site` to the partition clause.  Your data did not make this clear.